# Trying to code a python file which launch youtube video in vlc

Tags: python

Here is the full traceback and the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kimme\OneDrive\Bureau\dev\Programme-YT_to_VLC\FoxieYT.py", line 11, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(['"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\VideoLAN\VLC.lnk', youtube_url])
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1440, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access Denied
PS C:\Users\kimme\OneDrive\Bureau\dev\Programme-YT_to_VLC>
```

Here is my code :

```
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

youtube_url = simpledialog.askstring(title="Youtube reader", prompt="Enter youtube video url:")

subprocess.Popen(['"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\VideoLAN\VLC.lnk', youtube_url])
```

I don't know how to resolve this

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the full traceback?

Comment: There's a single double quotation mark in your command.